# Populating a UITableView within a UIViewController and changing data source with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to populate a `UITableView` that I put inside a `UIViewController`, underneath a `UISegmentedControl`, which is depicted in the picture:

[image]

Upon pressing any of the segments, I want the `UITableView` to be repopulated with a different set of data. Here is my relevant code:

```
@interface OTValuesViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;

@end

@implementation OTValuesViewController


- (IBAction)segmentValueChanged:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *segment = self.segmentControl;
    UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = navItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            addButton.action = @selector(addNewVision:);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 1:
            addButton.action = @selector(addNewPurpose:);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 2:
            addButton.action = @selector(addNewPlan:);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;
        default:
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            break;

    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UISegmentedControl *segment = self.segmentControl;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OTValuesTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *visions = [[OTVisionStore sharedStore] allVisions];
    NSArray *purposes = [[OTPurposeStore sharedStore] allPurposes];
    NSArray *plans = [[OTPlanStore sharedStore]allPlans];

    OTVision *vision = [visions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    OTVision *purpose = [purposes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    OTVision *plan = [plans objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *textLabel = [vision description];

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        textLabel = [vision description];
        cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {
        textLabel = [purpose description];
        cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
    }
    else{
        textLabel = [plan description];
        cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UISegmentedControl *segment = self.segmentControl;
    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        return [[[OTVisionStore sharedStore]allVisions]count];
    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {
        return [[[OTPurposeStore sharedStore]allPurposes]count];
    }
    else{
        return [[[OTPlanStore sharedStore]allPlans]count];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.title=@"Mission Statement";

    UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *rbbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                     target:self
                                                                     action:@selector(addNewVision:)];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = rbbi;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

My issue is: when I build and run the project, everything is fine -- the cells are populated in my default tab (vision). When I click a `UISegmentedControl` button, I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

If I remove:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

from my `viewDidLoad`, this error does not occur (though, the `UITableView` obviously doesn't get populated.) This leads me to believe that the error is derived from my populating the cells based on the `UISegmentedController's` selected segment, however, I do not know what is specifically causing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You try to use the current index path for all of your arrays, not just the applicable array. Try something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UISegmentedControl *segment = self.segmentControl;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OTValuesTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        NSArray *visions = [[OTVisionStore sharedStore] allVisions];
        OTVision *vision = [visions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *textLabel = [vision description];
        cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {
        NSArray *purposes = [[OTPurposeStore sharedStore] allPurposes];
        OTVision *purpose = [purposes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *textLabel = [purpose description];
        cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
    }
    else{
        NSArray *plans = [[OTPlanStore sharedStore]allPlans];
        OTVision *plan = [plans objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *textLabel = [plan description];
        cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem perfectly! Thanks so much -- I was really scratching my head over this one.